# Apply Yup Validation Only On The Fields Which Are Rendered (Shown) On The Page. Ignore other fields

Tags: reactjs, yup

I am new to react and yup, I am conditionally changing form fields. I want to apply validation only to those fields which are being rendered. Kindly guide me. Thank You.